# Confusion with Linux kernel

Tags: kernel

I am really confused with the kernel concepts.

I came to know that the kernel is between application and hardware, and that the kernel takes input from the applications and it will send the instructions to the hardware to process.

In Windows as per my knowledge I don't hear the word called kernel.

My doubt is here, what is a kernel actually?

Comment: Windows has a kernel too, with essentially the same functions. You seem to have understood what it does mainly, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I asked like , what are the functionalities of a kernel ? and why kernel word is not famous in windows ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(computing) - it's a very broad and generic question you have. As for the Windows part, that can't really be answered, and Window's kernel _is_ known to people who care about it. Most people don't (possibly because you can't really change it, so it's less "interesting" than in Linux).

Answer (score 5):

The kernel is pretty much what you say it is. It allows executables to communicate with the hardware. Simply put, the user interacts with high level software (the GUI interface for example) and the kernel is responsible for translating your requests to the CPU and devices (image [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kernel_Layout.svg)):

[image]

The kernel is also responsible for memory management, it deals with all your devices (sound cards, graphics cards, keyboard etc) and controls process management. Essentially, the kernel *is* the operating system. That's why it's called a *[kernel](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kernel)*, it is the core of the OS.

All OSes, including Windows have a kernel, you don't talk about it so much in the Windows world because you can't do anything about it. Since it is closed source, it is not modified by anyone but Microsoft so fewer people have access to the code or will write about it. It does most certainly exist however. The current Windows kernel is called "The NT kernel" and all of the recent (and not so recent) versions of Windows have been based on it.

For more information on kernels see these links:

- http://www.linfo.org/kernel.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_of_Windows_NT#Kernel_mode

Comment: Can we think like kernel is a OS ?

Comment: @user2720323 no, in a OS, you also have high-level applications. The configuration panel on Windows for example is part of the OS, but not of the kernel.

Comment: @user2720323 Think of the kernel as the most important part of an OS.

Comment: It's worth pointing out in the context of this answer what constitutes an "application" in that graphic: not only what is traditionally thought of as user applications but also the shell, security subsystem (to some extent; for example, the software that allows users to log in to the system), and so on.